# how to if else for type value double

Tags: java, if-statement

I have set

```
try {
    TradingHistory tradingHistory = RepositoryFactory.getTradingHistoryRepo().findbyStatusSinglemarket();
    String Symbol = tradingHistory.getSymbol();
    Double OrderQty = tradingHistory.getQty();
    String orderTypes = tradingHistory.getType();
    String type = tradingHistory.getPrice_type();
    System.out.println(Symbol+" | "+OrderQty+" | "+orderTypes);
    String IdSet = Integer.toString(tradingHistory.getId());
    String clord = "FM-";
    String clordid = clord.concat(IdSet);
    Double price = Double.valueOf(tradingHistory.getPrice());
    if(OrderQty < 100000 && orderTypes.equals("market")){
        System.out.println("marketOrder" +Symbol );
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have data like this one

```
Double OrderQty= 22222.22222222;
```

and

```
orderTypes="market";

GBPCHF | 22222.22222222 | market
```

So I want to use if

```
(OrderQty <100000 && orderTypes.equals("market")
```

I expected I can got

```
System.out.println("marketOrder" +Symbol );
```

but when I run that code I cannot got

System.out.println("marketOrder" +Symbol );

how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide us a description of what you are expecting to get? - I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: you have no doubles in your code, you have instances of Double. start by learning the difference between the two

Comment: See if there is any exception, try adding a catch block and catch Exception class? `try { ... }catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
oh i see i got error because of empty string thanks guys

Comment: Why are you using wrapper classes like `Double`? Use the primitives, `double`. Please stick to Java naming conventions, `camelCase` and not `PascalCase` for variable names.